# Cant get "=~" to work. Keep getting "[: =~: binary operator expected"

Tags: bash

When I try and use `if [ "$1" =~ "$regex" ]; then`

I keep on getting back the same error: `[: =~: binary operator expected`

Here is an example function where I get the error:

```
char_check() {
  regex='^[]0-9a-zA-Z,!^`@{}=().;/~_|[-]*$'
  if [ "$1" =~ "$regex" ]; then
    echo "No illegal characters."
  else
    echo "Illegal characters."
  fi
}
```

Any response would be a great help.

Comment: Please try with `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`

Comment: https://shellcheck.net  to validate your script, and yes `[   ]` does not support regex testing, also in bash avoid using `[  ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions require `[[ expression ]]` as shown in the [man page of bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Also you must not quote the regex itself, e.g. you should prefer `$regex` over `"$regex"`

```
char_check() {
  regex='^[]0-9a-zA-Z,!^`@{}=().;/~_|[-]*$'
  if [[ "$1" =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "No illegal characters."
  else
    echo "Illegal characters."
  fi
}
```

If you quote the regex then you are trying to match the *string*, not the *pattern*. In other words it will match the weird string '^[]0-9a-zA-Z,!^`@{}=().;/~_|[-]*$'

Comment: Not a literal `$regex` but all the chars in the variable `$regex` are escaped/quoted, since it is using a double quote. If you use a single quote that is when you will match a `\$regex`, try it with `set -x`